# Installing glib from git in mac os x and gettext

Tags: macos, unix, glib

I'm trying build glib from source in Mac OS X.

I've clone glib repo from gnome site.

The `autogen.sh` script seems to run fine. But when it starts it shows this message :

```
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
```

This seems spooky. However it finishes without showing any error. After spawning configure script it stops with the error :

```
checking libintl.h usability... no
checking libintl.h presence... no
checking for libintl.h... no
configure: error: 
*** You must have either have gettext support in your C library, or use the
*** GNU gettext library. (http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/gettext.html
```

Although i've install `gettext` from macports and it seems to be there :

```
arif@dev:~/sak/glib$ls /opt/local/lib/ | grep gettext
gettext
libgettextlib-0.18.3.dylib
libgettextlib.dylib
libgettextlib.la
libgettextpo.0.dylib
libgettextpo.a
libgettextpo.dylib
libgettextpo.la
libgettextsrc-0.18.3.dylib
libgettextsrc.dylib
libgettextsrc.la
```

One thing i've noticed that although `gettext` is installed, it does not have `pkg-config` file. Maybe that's why its happening .

```
arif@dev:~/sak/glib$ls /opt/local/lib/pkgconfig/ | grep gettext
```

comes out with nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into something similar and you might want to try to set CFLAGS="-L/opt/local/lib -I/opt/local/include". It seems that those are not included by default when running the gettext tests. You can either CFLAGS to the configure call or probably also to the autogen.sh